# How to share many binary files between source projects in one solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a smallish solution, with about under twenty projects. The solution used to also contain about six source projects written by a third party service provider, ACME. Now, finally, this other party is supplying us **only** with a handful of DLLs. I used to just included their source, one project per DLL, in the solution, and so I am looking for a neat way to include all these assemblies in the solution, so they can be referenced from the many projects that need them.

My immediately apparent options are:

1. Create an `AcmeAssembly` project, add all DLLs as project items set to copy to output.
2. Create an `AcmeAssembly` solution folder. Quicker and simpler than a 'binary-only' source project, but solution folders have the very, very large drawback of having no means of grouping the files without a solution file, i.e. outside of VS.
3. Create a NuGet package that includes all the required binaries. Then at least we also have a partly 'phycical' grouping in the `packages` folders. My problem here is I have never written a NuGet package, but I am not asking how to here. I am asking about three candidate solutions, and more will be welcome, and if NuGet wins, I get to learn to write a package.

I can't simply use the project's output `bin\debug` and `bin\release` folders. To me, these are strictly output folders, and nothing but other dependency assemblies should also be output there. Deleting the `bin` folder should have absolutely zero effect on a build, so that is certainly no place to store binaries.

Comment: I vote for NuGet. It's the preferred way to distribute assemblies.

Comment: Nuget for sure. Keeps thing very tidy.

Comment: It is not clear. Are you asking how to use your 3rd party or distribute? I have been working on large systems with hundreds of 3rd party dlls and hundreds projects. We do have a `bin` folder where we `1-` Have all dlls, ours and third party. `2-` we reference all of them from this bin. `3-` we build all projects to this bin. `4-` standalone projects are built into subdirectories under bin. -- we never have problems with compiling, packaging or distributing. Although, our build process has differences with programmers build process

Comment: With regards to your second point, could you clarify what you dont like about this? Im not sure Im understanding your point.

Comment: @chris.ellis I like to keep my solution folders nice and tidy, with an absolute minimum of files, with all files grouped into project and other folders. I can find no way to link a "solution" folder to a file system folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantages of nuget over the other solutions are:

1. Support for versioning
2. Support is built in into Visual Studio and MSBuild
3. No 'magic folders' that all developers need to have on their machines

Answer (score 0):

Create your Acme library folder (something like: C:\Source\Library\AcmeLibrary).  Put all of your Acme dll's in that folder.  Then create the Solution Folder in VS and add the existing items to it (don't add the folder, but the items in the C:\Source\Library\AcmeLibrary folder to the solution folder using "Add Existing Item..." menu selection).